Need clarification about gravitational potential energy and total mechanical energy
Consider this situation: "mass $m_1$ and mass $m_2$ are at the same height. $m_2$ is greater than $m_1$. If we define their current position to have zero potential energy, they have same potential energy. But if we define a position lower than their current positions to be zero potential energy, $m_2$ have higher potential energy. If we define a position higher than their current positions to be zero potential energy, $m_1$ have higher potential energy." What is the issue here? I ran into a question where it asked which one has a higher total mechanical energy. Help appreciated.. thank you

As stated in Wikipedia, "potential energy is the energy held by an object because of its position relative to other objects". Naturally the value of this energy is also relative.

You ask what is the issue here, but that's something you should clarify. Why did you expect anything else to happen? Can you explain physically what doesn't make sense to you here?

I was just starting to answer when this was closed. I will write some comments. The reason energy is important is that it is conserved. If you drop an object, gravity pulls it down. It loses height and gains speed. It loses potential energy and gains kinetic energy. The thing that matters is how much potential energy was lost and kinetic energy was gained. The thing that matters is changes in energy.

You get the same result if you drop an object at the top or bottom of a mountain. It doesn't matter if you started with a lot of potential energy or a little. Because we only care that the total amount of energy doesn't change, we don't care how much that total is. It seems contradictory.


Consider this situation: "mass $m_1$ and mass $m_2$ are at the same
height. $m_2$ is greater than $m_1$. If we define their current
position to have zero potential energy, they have same potential
energy.

$m_1$ and $m_2$ don't "have" potential energy. Individual masses  don't possess potential energy. Potential energy is a system property that depends on the configuration of the system.
In this case it is the $m_1$-Earth and $m_2$-Earth systems that have potential energy. So the $m_1$-Earth and $m_2$-Earth systems have different potential energy if the product of their separation and mass is different. If the separations are the same but the masses are different, or vise-versa, their system potential energies will be different.
Bottom line: You can't define the potential energy of the unequal masses at the same height above the Earth to both be zero.
Hope this helps.

I think (guess?) the question is assuming that the ground is the zero PE level, gravity points down, and that both masses are some height off the ground.
But it's a poorly-worded question and you are right to point out the confusion.  Energy is dependent on frame of reference.
An analogous situation could be with two race cars.  The first one is ten meters to the left and ten meters forward with respect to the second one.  Which is closer to the finish line?  Well if the finish line is fifty meters ahead of both of them, then the first one is obviously closer.  But if the finish line is fifty meters behind them, then the second one is closer.  And if the finish line is some kind of diagonal stripe then its possible they could be crossing it simultaneously at an angle.
A contrived example, maybe, but the point is that many calculations are dependent on frame of reference.  So the question is not completely clear if the reference frame isn't stated.
